# How exit socket properly with Nodejs net

Tags: node.js, sockets

I have a problem in attempting to kill all processes inside a socket function in nodejs net: loops keep running after the socket disconnects. Is there a way to kill all processes called by the socket?

```
net.createServer(function (socket) {

  socket.on('end', function () {
    //How kill all processes of the current socket ???
  });
  socket.on('error', function () {
    //How kill all processes of the current socket ???
  });

  i=0;
  setInterval(function () {//Waiting other peer for 5sec
    i++;
    console.log("loop");
    if(i>=10){
      clearInterval(this);
    }
  }, 1000);

}).listen(1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
socket.disconect(0);
```

should terminate the connection.

Comment: Thx for your reponse, but socket.disconect is an socket.io function, in my case im using socket TCP from net library

Comment: Try socket.destroy(); or socket.end(). [Reference to Documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/net.html#net_socket_destroy)

Comment: In case it works comment here. I would appreciate that. :)

Comment: @han0idx which version are you using?

Comment: my node version is v4.3.1

Answer (score 0):

Here a shot snippet if you want to try it on your computer:

```
var net = require('net');

net.createServer(function(socket) {

    setInterval(function () {//Loop
     console.log("tick");
    }, 1000);

    socket.on('close', function () {
      socket.end();
      socket.destroy();
      console.log("socket closed");
    });

}).listen(1000);
```

`socket.end()` and `socket.destroy()` are not killing functions inside `net.createServer` the program keep ticking closing socket :S